# self created .deb package has versioning problems

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, packaging, deb

I did my first steps in creating a PPA, containing a recent fossil version.

I unpacked the tarball and ran `bzr dh-make fossil 1.32 ../fossil-src-stable.tar.gz` on it, editet the debian files till compilation worked and built my deb with

```
bzr builddeb -S -- -uc -us
pbuilder-dist utopic build fossil_1.32-ppa1.dsc
```

so far it was hard, but worked somehow.

No to my problem, as you can see, I built fossil version 1.32 and the deb is named `fossil_1.32-ppa1_amd64.deb` simple as by following the [tutorials](http://packaging.ubuntu.com).

Now, when I try to install my deb, it tells me, that a more recent version is already installed and installation aborts.

Apt-cache policy tells me, that the installed version is lower:

```
$ apt-cache policy fossil
fossil:
  Installiert:           1:1.29-1
  Installationskandidat: 1:1.29-1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:1.29-1 0
```

Question 1: What is this "1:" preceding the version number?
Question 2: What kind of Version will I have to give my deb to be installed?

I already tried bzr `dh-make fossil 1:1.32 ../fossil-src-stable.tar.g` but that won't even give me a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it. The deb package build gets its version number not from the `version` field in the `control` file, but from the `changelog` entry.